# How to configure wso2 AM logger to log adding a user and role

Tags: wso2

What WSO2 API Manager (in management console) logger needs to be changed to "DEBUG" in order to log adding a user and deleting a user & adding a role & deleting a role.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable debug logs for the following package

```
org.wso2.carbon.user.core
```

You can either add it through management console or, by configuration files. In order to add through configuration file, go to log4j.properties file which is inside $APIM_HOME/repository/conf folder and add the following entry,

```
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.user.core=DEBUG
```